Capacitance coefficients of two enclosed spheres
I was reviewing G.B. Jeffery's work titled On a Form of the Solution of Laplace's Equation Suitable for Problems Relating to Two Spheres. To access the full text, you need to click "DOWNLOAD PDF" at the bottom of the page.
While most of the derivations are understandable, despite not showing every step, I encountered an issue on the penultimate page. I cannot figure out the origin of the marked term in the series.
Here is the relevant section:



I understand the rest of the series, but this particular term eludes me.
I consulted Smythe's Static and Dynamic Electricity, specifically volume 5.08, which discusses the scenario of two spheres:



The left figure illustrates the configuration for calculating the capacitance coefficient $q_{22}$. However, Smythe mentions that this capacitance coefficient is not significant. This is confusing to me because:



Moreover, in chapter 5.081, Smythe only provides the coefficient for the right figure (b), not for the left figure (a):



I'm having trouble understanding why the capacitance coefficient $q_{22}$ for the left figure isn't important, and how this ties back to Jeffery's marked term. Can you provide any insights into this discrepancy?
